# C# converting collections to lists and into 1d dapper ORM

Tags: c#, sqlite, dapper

looking for some advice and explanations.

Im using Micro-ORM Dapper to take a table out of SQLite and do stuff with it.

Bind:

```
public static List<Airport> LoadAirports()
    {
        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
        {
            var output = cnn.Query<Airport>("select * from Airport", new DynamicParameters());
            return output.ToList();
        }            
    }
```

Class:

```
class Airport
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public string IATA { get; set; }
    public string PortType { get; set; }
    public string PortOwner { get; set; }
    public string MotherPort { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool IsApplyMeetAndGreet { get; set; }
    public decimal MeetAndGreet { get; set; }        
}
```

Main:

```
private void LoadAirportsList()
    {
        Airports = SqliteDataAccess.LoadAirports();
    }
```

This creates a variable "Airports" which i believe is a collection of arrays. My problem is that i can never seem to extract any specific information from them.

For example i want to acquire the name of every airport in the list I only seem to be able to return the entire collection, ive been reading into multidimensional arrays and flattening 2d arrays but i always get errors about types where functions cant be iterated over them.

I would try

```
for (int i = 0; i < Airports.Count; i++)
        {
            Assigner = Airports[i];
        }
```

With the intention of then iterating through all the airports to then assign each .Name to a list variable. Sigh as of yet no avail. Grateful for any assistance anyone can provide.

Comment: Are you sure it is collection of arrays? I believe it a collection of Airport class objects. You can loop thru the collection and get individual airport names by doing `Airports[i].Name`. or can use linq to get all the names in on collection as `var names  = Airports.Select(airport => airport.Name);`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Airports.Select will return "{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<LocalPN.Airport, string>}" How do i then get the Names from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some direction from @Chetan Ranpariya, Eventually figured it out.

```
var PortNames = Airports.Select(airport => airport.Name);
```

Solved the initial acquisition of the specific element within the object list.

Initially i thought you could iterate over the PortNames variable at this stage but its still considered a method and you cannot operate over methods.

So: `List<string> PortNameList = PortNames.ToList();`

Even though the collection is output as a list its a list of objects so once you've parsed the element you then to make THAT a list of strings. Which you can then operate over using `for (int i = 0; i < PortNameList.Count; i++)` doing whatever you need with those individual string values, in my instance i used the loop to add them to a comboBox.

If im mistaken about any of this please let me know.